# Django and Apache WSGIScriptAlias not handling deep URLs

Tags: django, apache

The tutorials, guides and even other posts here on SO dealing with how to deploy Django on Apache seem to assume that by default when using the `WSGIScriptAlias` directive all deep links under that alias are handled by the script as well (usually demonstrated by visiting the '/' and `/admin` page). For me that seems not to be the case. Requests to the root at `api.mydomain.com/v1/` are handled by my Django app, but `api.mydomain.com/v1/users/` (with or without trailing slash) generate Apache's 404 "Not Found. The requested URL was not found on this server." message.

Is there a setting I've missed somewhere that handles these deep links? For example for SPA's I'm used to having to redirect all requests to a front controller.

Here's my Apache configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName api.mydomain.com

    WSGIPassAuthorization On
    WSGIScriptAlias /v1/ /var/www/django_app/django_app/wsgi.py

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.mydomain.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.mydomain.com/privkey.pem
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the trailing slash from the `WSGIScriptAlias` directive's URL-path:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /v1 /var/www/django_app/django_app/wsgi.py
```